# Change colours of ggplot2 (R) using column names

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data frame (see below) and I want to change the colors of the plot in ggplot2 so that all the A's are colored red, B's blue, C's black, and D's yellow.

```
myDF

label    A    B    C    D
lab1 0.69 0.65 0.73 0.71
lab2 0.43 0.41 0.47 0.41
lab3 0.53 0.47 0.57 0.53
lab4 0.55 0.47 0.60 0.55
lab5 0.53 0.47 0.58 0.53
```

I tried the following:

```
p <- ggplot(myDF, aes(x=label)) 
     + geom_point(aes(y=A))
     + geom_point(aes(y=B))
     + geom_point(aes(y=C))
     + geom_point(aes(y=D))
     + scale_colour_manual(values=c("A"="red", "B"= "blue", "C"="black", "D"="yellow"))
```

But it gives me an error. If I don't add the scale_colour_manual part, it gives the correct plot but all black dots. How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rearrange your data from "wide" to "long"; i.e. make the column names A, B, etc into a new column. There are lots of tools to do this, from reshape, to tidyr, etc.

Comment: Put `+`s at the end of the line, not the beginning, or (possibly depending on how you run it) you'll get errors because subsequent lines won't be included in the call. Also, it's a much better idea to reshape your data to long form here so you only need one `geom_point` call here. To work with what you've got, you can just specify the color in each `geom_point` call.

Comment: @alistaire actually, I used the colour= in aes of geom_point and that didn't work. but in any case, wide to long is the way to go.

Comment: You can do it as-is, i.e. `ggplot(myDF, aes(x = label)) + geom_point(aes(y = A, color = 'A')) + geom_point(aes(y = B, color = 'B')) + geom_point(aes(y = C, color = 'C')) + geom_point(aes(y = D, color = 'D')) + scale_colour_manual(NULL, values = c(A = "red", B = "blue", C = "black", D = "yellow"))`, but long form is ultimately much more useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get your data into long format first. And I'd reconsider yellow on white.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

myDF %>% 
  gather(key, value, -label) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(label, value)) + geom_point(aes(color = key)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "black", "yellow"))
```